# Get Exact value by key or id from json file using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json file containing with **50,000 user details**. i need to display the user details like **name , mobile and address** by using user **id**. am done this with below code **successfully** **but**, it's taking too much time (**more than 15 seconds**) to get data and display on a html page.

so, please help me to reduce the time consumption to fetch data from json file.

html code is

```
<input type="text" id="search">
<input type="submit" id="submit">
```

i have json file (convertcsv.json) with below details

```
[
 {
   "id": 22313,
   "Name": "BABU",
   "Address": "Hyderabad"
 },
 {
  "id": 21314,
  "Name": "Raju",
  "Address": "BENGALURU"
 }
]
```

the actual JQuery script is

```
<script>
  $('#submit').on('click', function(){
    var searchField = $('#search').val();
    var regex = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
    var output = '<div class="row">';
    var count =0;
    $.getJSON('convertcsv.json', function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(key, val){
        if (val.id==searchField ) {
          output += '<div class="dataContain">';
          output += '<p><span style="font-weight:bold;"> id: </span>'+val.id+ '</p>';
          output += '<p><span style="font-weight:bold;"> Name: </span>'+val.Name + '</p>';
          output+='<p><span style="font-weight:bold;">Address: </span><span class="status">' + val.Address+'<span class="circle"></span></span></p>';
          output += '</div>';             
          count++;
        }


      });
     /// alert(count);
if(count==0){
output += 'No Records Found'
}
//alert(output)
      output += '</div>';
      //$('#results').toggle();
      $('#results').html(output);
    });
});
```

then the result is displayed in  tag

```
<div id="results"> Result Displayed here, i need to improve time, please help me, thanks in advance</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try using `filter` in JavaScript?

Comment: sorry @AliShahbaz , i don't have knowledge about filters, please can you give me  reference code about **filters** in JavaScript

Comment: I have added the answer with `filter` example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var json = [
 {
   "id": 22313,
   "Name": "BABU",
   "Address": "Hyderabad"
 },
 {
  "id": 21314,
  "Name": "Raju",
  "Address": "BENGALURU"
 }
]

console.log(json.filter(x=> x.id == '22313'))
```

Load your JSON file and then filter like above example, then create HTML from resulted JSON array.

**EDIT 1**

```
$.getJSON('convertcsv.json', function(data) {

      // filter results given searchField then loop through from resulted JSON array
      // filter returns an array

      let result = data.filter(x=> x.id == searchField);
      $.each(result, function(key, val){

          output += '<div class="dataContain">';
          output += '<p><span style="font-weight:bold;"> id: </span>'+val.id+ '</p>';
          output += '<p><span style="font-weight:bold;"> Name: </span>'+val.Name + '</p>';
          output+='<p><span style="font-weight:bold;">Address: </span><span class="status">' + val.Address+'<span class="circle"></span></span></p>';
          output += '</div>';             
          count++;

        });


      });
```

**EDIT 2**

Load JSON when document is ready and store into variable.

```
var jsonUsers;
$(document).ready(function () {
     $.getJSON('convertcsv.json', function(data) {
     jsonUsers = data;
  });
});
```

Now when click on button, filter out results from `jsonUsers`

Comment: but , i have a json data in a file named as convertcsv.json , then how can i load the file to filter @Ali Shahbaz

Comment: thank you @ali Shahbaz, it's taking 15 seconds to fetch data  in incognito window.

Comment: Was it helpful? Your file might take time to load, but cutting the loop iterations definitely cuts time.

Comment: yes its helpful, how to load json file on body load?

Answer (score 1):

***thank you very much*** @Ali Shahbaz , the **final answer** is.,

```
var jsonUsers;
$(document).ready(function () {
   $.getJSON('convertcsv.json', function(data) {
     jsonUsers = data;
   });
});


  // filter results given searchField then loop through from resulted JSON array
  // filter returns an array

  let result = jsonUsers.filter(x=> x.id == searchField);
  $.each(result, function(key, val){

      output += '<div class="dataContain">';
      output += '<p><span style="font-weight:bold;"> id: </span>'+val.id+ '</p>';
      output += '<p><span style="font-weight:bold;"> Name: </span>'+val.Name + '</p>';
      output+='<p><span style="font-weight:bold;">Address: </span><span class="status">' + val.Address+'<span class="circle"></span></span></p>';
      output += '</div>';             
      count++;

    });
```

now it's working very well, without consuming loading time.

Comment: That's great .. :)